# Unkown column in on clause while it is present

Tags: mysql

Having an issue joining another table.

```
SELECT rank FROM  
    (
        SELECT highscores.playerID, (@rowID := @rowID + 1) AS rank 
        FROM highscores, (SELECT @rowID := 0) r
        JOIN overall ON highscores.playerID = overall.playerID
        WHERE skillID = ?
        ORDER BY skillExperience DESC, highscores.updateTime ASC
    ) data  
WHERE data.playerID = ?
```

Keeps telling me `Unknown column 'highscores.playerID' in 'on clause'` while it is present. I've looked on the internet for solutions to this problem, but I'm not finding the solution that will work for me.

Is the row number causing issue's here? If so how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the highscores table with the overall table first:

```
SELECT rank FROM  
    (
        SELECT highscores.playerID, (@rowID := @rowID + 1) AS rank 
        FROM
          highscores JOIN overall ON highscores.playerID = overall.playerID,
          (SELECT @rowID := 0) r
        WHERE skillID = ?
        ORDER BY skillExperience DESC, highscores.updateTime ASC
    ) data  
WHERE data.playerID = ?
```

in your original query you were joining the derived table r with the overall table:

```
(SELECT @rowID := 0) r
JOIN overall ON highscores.playerID = overall.playerID
```

which would not work because highscores.playerID is not found since the highscores table will be joined separately.

Comment: Wow alright well that fixed my issue,why does it have to be after the Join?

Comment: Thanks that explains why!